# How to execute build task of another project using custom Task in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy, task

I have a custom task in Gradle like this:

```
class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def dosomework() {
        //todo
    }
}
```

I want to execute build task of another project using my custom task. 
How can I do this?
the project that i want to execute it's build task is located in `D://AndroidProj`.
Can anyone help me?
 Thanks

Comment: You could use a composite build and `dependsOn` as shown here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#separate_composite